# how can i develop an Android application in Hindi language ?

Tags: android

## I want to develop an application that support English and Hindi##

> 1.i want to create this application for 4.0 ice cream sandwich

Comment: wats problem it will be developed like other app

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html refer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is done by storing values for text displayed in different resource files for each language.

Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

it shall solve your problem

The resource structure:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-hi/
           strings.xml
```

Add the string values for each locale into the appropriate file.

At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

For example, the following are some different string resource files for different languages.

```
English (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>

Hindi, /values-hi/strings.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">कखग</string>
    <string name="hello_world">ककक</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: but how about hindi how can i get hindi font and then use it

Comment: see edits above ... in this case i used nepali unicode to type in the devanagari script which is the same for hindi!