# How i can do localization on my all viewtext in android studio on a button click

Tags: android, localization

How i can change language of my sigup activitie from default to Hindi click on a button .
I created a resource file values-hi.
So how i can get default resource folder to hindi resource folder .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i develop an Android application in Hindi language ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605668/how-can-i-develop-an-android-application-in-hindi-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `btnHindi` is a button in `MainActivity`. Then you can add click listener on that button to change the language of your Activity as follows:

```
    btnHindi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Locale locale1 = new Locale("hi"); 
                Locale.setDefault(locale1);
                Configuration config1 = new Configuration();
                config1.locale = locale1;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config1, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class );
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```